# Python merging excel files in directory

Tags: python-3.x

I have thousands of files inside a directory with this pattern `YYYY/MM/DD/HH/MM`:

```
201901010000.xlsx
201901010001.xlsx,
201901010002.xlsx,
201801010000.xlsx,
201801010001.xlsx,
201801010002.xlsx,
```

I wants to merge file by  begin with same `YYYY`(`2018` & `2019` separate file) wise into one excel file.like below

this is first file

```
201901010000.xlsx,
201901010001.xlsx,
201901010002.xlsx,
```

this is second file

```
201801010000.xlsx,
201801010001.xlsx,
201801010002.xlsx,
```

Comment: How many sheets does each file have? Do you want to concatenate the rows of files that are being merged?

Comment: there are only one sheet,all files have same header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to parse each file and concatenate by pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

my_path = "c:\\temp\\"

for year in ['2008', '2009']:
    buf = []
    year_files = glob.glob(my_path + year+"*.xlsx")
    for file in year_files:
        df = pd.read_excel(file)
        buf.append(df)
    year_df = pd.concat(buf)
    year_df.to_excel(year+".xlsx")
```

Comment: thanx for your support, i didn't understand in above code, where i have to mention the file path and full file name

Comment: @GaneshM added my_path variable to the code, which holds base location of input files. output file with be in the current directory, where you launch python. Or you can specify full path in to_excel function.

Comment: Thanks,this is exactly what i was looking for